# mysql select records with greatest sum given constraints on other values

Tags: mysql, sum, max, constraints

I've looked around but perhaps I'm not using the right terminology.

I have a table with 4 columns where I want to find the subset of records that 'optimize' one columns sum, based on constraints against the other columns. I basically want to mimic Excel's 'solver' add-in through MySQL.

For example, in the table below, I want to pick the exact 6 Brands that sum to the largest total 'Value' while (1) having a total 'price' <= 600 and (2) has at most 2 of any specific 'Type' value (eg, sum of A's B's, C's, D's, and E's <= 2 each).

I've tried using a running count, but that isn't getting me far. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

`Brand     | Type | Price | Value |
Chrysler   |  A   |  93   |  46.8 |
Ford       |  D   |  98   |  46.3 |
Oldsmobile |  C   |  92   |  45.6 |
Saturn     |  D   |  89   |  45.6 |
Plymouth   |  A   | 104   |  45.3 |
Toyota     |  E   |  90   |  42.6 |
Honda      |  C   |  89   |  39.8 |
Subaru     |  C   |  90   |  38.9 |
Jeep       |  C   |  70   |  37.8 |
Buick      |  B   |  73   |  36.4 |
Cadillac   |  A   |  83   |  35.4 |
Nissan     |  A   |  77   |  34.6 |
Cherry     |  E   |  71   |  34.6 |
Fiat       |  E   |  75   |  33.5 |
Mercedes   |  B   |  79   |  33.3 |
Lexus      |  A   |  81   |  31.9 |
BMW        |  B   |  71   |  30.2 |
Volvo      |  B   |  72   |  29.3 |
Peugot     |  E   |  58   |  29.1 |
Kia        |  C   |  59   |  28.2 |
Audi       |  E   |  59   |  27.9 |
Volkswagen |  B   |  63   |  26.9 |
Mitsubishi |  C   |  61   |  26.6 |
Chevrolet  |  A   |  71   |  25.3 |
Acura      |  B   |  57   |  24.5 |`

Comment: Please also provide the desired result for clarity. Actually I have no idea what you want to do. Your requirement suggests, that there can be multiple A's and B's and so on for each brand, but as far as I can see there's no brand even having 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of comparing all combinations of your rows six at a time, using a six-way self-join of your table (!!).  This finds the top value combinations for total prices less than 600. (Notice that the prices less than six hundred constraint isn't a constraint at all in your dataset, because there's no individual price over 100). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33fba/15/0

I am sorry, I don't get what you're trying to do with the As, Bs, Cs, etc.

```
SELECT SUM(a.price+b.price+c.price+d.price+e.price+f.price) AS price,  
       SUM(a.value+b.value+c.value+d.value+e.value+f.value) AS value,
       a.brand AS a, b.brand AS b, c.brand AS c, 
       d.brand AS d, e.brand AS e, f.brand AS f
  FROM t AS a
  JOIN t AS b ON  a.Brand < b.Brand
  JOIN t AS c ON  b.Brand < c.Brand
  JOIN t AS d ON  c.Brand < d.Brand
  JOIN t AS e ON  d.Brand < e.Brand
  JOIN t AS f ON  e.Brand < f.Brand
 GROUP BY a.brand, b.brand, c.brand, d.brand, e.brand, f.brand
HAVING SUM(a.price+b.price+c.price+d.price+e.price+f.price) <= 600
 ORDER BY  SUM(a.value+b.value+c.value+d.value+e.value+f.value) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```